# Как выводить всех учеников, которые должны произвести оплату?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Пишу на PHP сайт для учета данных, оплаты и посещаемости учеников. Тех, кто приходит к репетитору.
В MySQL есть таблица **pays**, в которую заносится последняя оплата ученика. И есть таблица **dates**, куда добавляются даты посещения каждого ученика.
**Оплата производится за 8 занятий**.
 
**Вопрос:** никак не могу додуматься, как можно сделать, чтобы выводить всех учеников, которые должны произвести оплату и у которых **седьмое или восьмое занятие по счету**? И чтобы не исчезало, пока не добавлено в таблицу **pays**.

Comment: Если не сложно приведите структуру ваших таблиц, как вы храните количество занятий, как связаны занятия и ученики? Ученики и их оплата?

Comment: Это похоже на важную доменную логику. Если у вас не миллионы учеников, то перенесите её из базы данных в код - лучше в отдельный метод/класс и напишите на это тесты.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT dates.user_id FROM dates
LEFT JOIN pays ON pays.user_id = dates.user_id
WHERE pays.id IS NULL
GROUP BY dates.user_id 
HAVING COUNT(dates.user_id) IN (7,8)
```

Берем все записи из dates, джойним pays с оплатами, делаем условие того, что оплаты не было произведено, группируем по user_id и смотрим чтобы по пользователю совпадало условие что у него 7 или 8 занятие.

Вы спросили про количество посещений во второй месяц, пока самое простое,что придумал, так это так, получилось конечно как-то помоему колхозно, но ладно.

Выбираем все даты, джойним pays, групируем по user_id, смотрим если кол-во разных дат посещений входит равно 7*кол-ву оплат или 8*кол-во оплат, (кол-во оплат минимум равно 1), то пользователь входит в интервал и его можно предупредить. У pays обязательно должен быть уникальный идентификатор (id), dates обязательно должна иметь дату посещения (date).

```
SELECT dates.user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT pays.id)+1 pcount FROM dates
LEFT JOIN pays ON pays.user_id = dates.user_id
GROUP BY dates.user_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dates.date) IN (7*pcount, 8*pcount)
```

Как короче и эффектнее написать второй, не пришло пока в голову.

Comment: А как быть, если на второй месяц количество посещений прибавится еще на +8? И в базе pays.id уже будет оплата за прошлый месяц?

Comment: @bakusite А вы про это не писали)) Вот написал решение на SQL для задачи, обновил ответ) Ночь, оригинальнее решения пока не пришло в голову)

Comment: Очень круто и гениально!!!

Comment: @bakusite Спасибо за такую высокую оценку ответа :)

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dates.date) IN (7*pcount, 8*pcount)` -> `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dates.date)%pcount IN (7, 8)` !!!